# How to use font families to make my document (exam - test) more beautiful and readable?

Tags: fonts

I would like to ask the community not a technical question, but a question regarding the aesthetic side of a document created in Latex. I am using `exam` or `article` documentclass, using `pdfLaTeX`, `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX` to write exam papers or tests, or even review papers for my students, mainly for mathematics but also other subjects as Language, History, Geography, Science etc.

My tests have mainly three parts, as you can see from the images. In the first image you can see the title of the test, which is the same in most of the documents with small variations such as date, subject, unit number etc.

In the second image you can see part of the main body of the test, which includes mostly questions and exercises. In the third image, you can see the footers (page 2 from 4) and headers.

My question is: How can I use the font families `LaTeX`, `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX` offer me (`\rmfamily`, `\sffamily`, `\ttfamily` or others) to make my document more beautiful and readable? For example, would it be a good idea to use the sans family (`\sffamily`) for the title and the serif family (`\rmfamily`) for the main body of the paper, or vice versa? What about the footers and headers? Is it better to use just one font family for the whole document?

Any options, any ideas are welcome, please feel free to advise. In the examples below I use the same font in the entire document, namely `CMU Concrete`, which is a Serif typewriter-like (mono) font.

[image: Title - Image1]
[image: Main body - Image2]
[image: Footers - headers - Image 3]

Comment: This question seems a bit open-ended, and also does not have any source code to modify. That makes it difficult to answer.

Comment: I didn't include any code in my question, as I don't need any technical advice. I don't ask how to change or how to choose fonts, or which packages support Greek etc. I can manage these. I just ask your opinion how to use the different fonts in different parts of my document to create a more beautiful one without overdo it. Which is better looking for you, the classical serif font at the title and the modern sans font at the main body or vice versa? Is overdoing using three or more fonts families in one document? Shall the footers and heaters have different font from  the title and main body?

Comment: Unfortunately, this means i can’t easily, for example, show you an image of what your page looks like with different fonts.

Comment: I see. Surely I can upload the code just thought the code isn't minimal and includes many other objects not concerning  fonts as numbering lists, tables, boxes, tikz pictures etc. which would make my question even more difficult to read and answer. So you suggest me to change the fonts, see how it looks like and decide. OK. I just wanted the expertise, experience, wisdom, perceptive eyes of this wonderful community. It could many of you had the same question and had the answer long before me, as you have seen hundreds of Latex documents and tests.

Comment: As this question is likely to be closed as opinion-based, you might consider rephrasing it to stress functionality rather than aesthetics.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you look through the [Greek](https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-greek) and [multilingual](https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-greek) fonts on CTAN, try out the font packages, and pick the one you like best.  I would recommend you use LuaLaTeX as your first choice of engine.

You might start by looking at the options for `\usepackage[...]{fontsetup}`, including `[default]` (New Computer Modern Book), `[gfsneohellenic]`, and `[libertinus]`.  All of these have different, attractive Greek text fonts and full math support.